How to create a Map in apex to effectively bring soql outside loop for 2 objects manipulation
I have 2 objects , Account (look up to Acc landing) and Account Landing. Account landing has a field called accountid, which I need to update if the account has a acc landing associated to it.
My trigger on account is calling the below code but I want to move the soql outside the for loop. I have tried so many options, cant seem to figure it out:
public class AccountTriggerHandler_AccIdOnLanding {
    public static void updateLanding(List<Account> accLst){
                
        List<Account_Landing__c> newAccLandLst = new List<Account_Landing__c>();
                              
        for (Account acc : accLst )       {                                      
            List<Account_Landing__c> AccLandLst = [select id,Account_ID__c from Account_Landing__c where id =: acc.Account_Landing__c limit 1] ;
            
            AccLandLst[0].Account_ID__c = acc.id;
            newAccLandLst.add(AccLandLst[0]);
            
        }
        update newAccLandLst;
    }
}


Have you looked through the question that your previous question was marked a duplicate of? Did you look at the comment I left that summarized that question?

Hey Derek, yes. And I was able to modify that piece of code and it works great. This scenario is different and I am really stuck

This scenario appears to be basically the same as your previous question, and the previous solution (i.e. loop once to gather ids, query and build a map, loop again to pull the value from the map) should work here too. It'd help if you would [edit] your question to show us some of the things you've tried. If you're getting error messages, it's important to include them here too, verbatim, including the stack trace (trying to shorten the error messages means you're almost certainly going to remove important information, so literally just copy/paste them)

public static void updateLanding(List<Account> accLst){
    if(accLst != null && accLst.size() > 0){
        
        //Map to store landing id and related account id
        Map<Id, Id> mapAccIdByAccLandingId = new Map<Id, Id>();
        for(Account recAcc : accLst){
            if(recAcc.Account_Landing__c != null){
                mapAccIdByAccLandingId.put(recAcc.Account_Landing__c, recAcc.Id);
            }
        }

        if(!mapAccIdByAccLandingId.isEmpty()){
            
            List<Account_Landing__c> AccLandLst = [select id,Account_ID__c from Account_Landing__c where id IN :mapAccIdByAccLandingId.keySet()];
            for(Account_Landing__c recLanding : AccLandLst){
                recLanding.Account_ID__c = mapAccIdByAccLandingId.get(recLanding.Id);
            }

            update AccLandLst;
        }
    }
}

Hopefully it might help(You might need to adjust if you see any errors). I'd highly recommend learning about "Bulkification" in apex and using different data structures.

Thanks! My mistake was trying to create a map with just 1 object, creating the map with two different ids is perfect and works !! Thanks again!
